# What if too many parameters in mysql query in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

This table has many parameters, and when i do insert it's like this, (... is for demo propose)

```
    const sqlCmd = `insert into Consumer (key, secret, ..., version)
                values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;

try {
    const param = [myTable.key, myTable.secret, ..., myTable.version];
    return await dbPool.execSqlCmd(sqlCmd, param)
}
```

Is there a way to avoid so many ?s  ?

Comment: what's the problem with too many?

Comment: just want to see if there's another way

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you use one `?` parameter placeholder for each scalar value you want to pass to the SQL statement. No more, no less.

If you want fewer `?` placeholders, then you must pass fewer parameters. You can do this by:

- Omitting some columns from the INSERT statement. The row inserted will use the DEFAULT value declared for the column, or else NULL if there is no default.
- Using a constant expression in the VALUES clause for some columns, instead of a parameter. I mean this can be a constant literal, like a numeric or string or date, or it can be an expression or function, which will be evaluated, and the resulting value used for the INSERT.